# How to know if MI phone user has enabled Auto Start for an app

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have an app that I'd like working for a user only if he has enabled push notifications.

On most Android phones this is not a problem since I request for permission to send push notifications and get it through the app code itself, but on MI phones, the user has to proactively open the Security app and give "Auto Start" permission to my app. And that cannot be done programmatically (I've checked).

Now I can inform the user when he downloads my app that he needs to do this, and would like to show the full app to him only after he's done this.

For this, however, I need to know whether (and when) the user has given me that permission.

The question is, how do I find out that the user has done this - gone to the Security app and given my app the Auto Start permission?

I'd greatly appreciate any tips. Thank you.

Comment: Any solutions??